# Is “I repeated him” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I’m listening to an audio book where a character hears what another tells her through an ear piece, then relays what she heard to others. This is a pretty central thing in the book, so it happens quite regularly. When the character just repeats what the other one said, the author writes “I repeated him.”

This is a way of using “repeat” I’ve never seen before, and every time it comes up on the recording it takes me out of the story. I would have written it as “I repeated what he said.” But given that this is a professionally edited, traditionally published book, I wonder if this may be actually correct, just not common in current use?

Comment: It would probably be good to include the title of the book in your post

Comment: Strangely, the quote was added after my answer which includes it, was posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane I rolled that back. It lead me down a complete rabbit hole where I ended up at a tea party with Hegel and Derrida :) We shouldn't be adding random "context" to fix a question that should be closed until the author provides the actual context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, I'm not sure you can really repeat a person, but apparently it's permissible.

However, when the author says, "I repeated him," what the author means is "I repeated what he said."

Comment: Right, you can't repeat a person unless your are drawing him, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it sounds a little off (as with "explain me") but [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repeat) has

> **repeat**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1.1** Say again (something said or written by someone else)

with an example usage

> *And to overcome him is to repeat him, with a difference.*

Comment: I looked for the quote because it still sounded weird to me. I only found one source. Here’s a bit more context: “If we are to overcome Hegel (and modernity), then we must inhabit him—which we do, whether we know it or not. And to overcome him is to repeat him, with a difference.” So I don’t think this is used in the same sense as in the book. Or at least this has a poetic slant, which the book I’m listening does not. It’s a novel with pretty a pretty plain style.

Comment: It isn't uncommon for someone to say "Don't repeat me", but less common to hear "Don't repeat *what I said*" or "Don't repeat *my words*".